# Pass a variable to sibling from functional component to index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props

I'm trying to pass the variable from my useState, called `selectedFile` in AddFile.js, to the sibling file called 'index.js'. When I try to pass it and call it with `import { AddFile, selectedFile } from "./AddFile.js";` I get the error of `Attempted import error: 'selectedFile' is not exported from ./AddFile.js.` so I know it's not exporting and I don't know how to go about exporting this variable to a sibling. Can someone please help me? The AddFile.js is below. Thank you so much for the help!!

```
export function AddFile() {
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState('');
  console.log(selectedFile);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label> Add your own template!</label>
       <input
              type="file"
              name="file_name"
              value={selectedFile}
              onChange={(e) => setSelectedFile(e.target.value)}
            />
    </div>
   
  );
};
```

Comment: You can't just import the variable that's created in the function scope. You can pass it via props, probably by lifting the state up to the parent.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Hi, Roberto, thank you for replying. How would I go about doing that? I read that in alot of articles but I'm not sure which one applied/was helpful for me.

Comment: I'm reading this article. Does this apply the same way even I'm using a hook? Where I don't have the this.states. Also, I'm using functional components and this resource shows class components.

Comment: It does, just lift the useState hook up to the components parent

Comment: The problem I was having is I'm playing with a project that is one big class component and I didn't know how/ where to put the hook in. So I made this functional component

Comment: Put the hook whereever you are using `<AddFile`

Comment: Can't a hook only go in a function? I'm calling the <AddFile/> in the JSX in return()